# Do any relics other than the Vault Hunter Relic boost Rare Item Chance?

Tags: borderlands-2

With the preorder bonus I got the Vault Hunter Relic which gives +5% rare item chance. The problem with that is I have never and will never equip another relic unless it has a better rare item chance.

So far (1/3rd of the way into playthrough 2) I've never seen another relic with + rare item chance. Are there any others, or am I going to be wearing this one forever?

Comment: I hope there are some. In the first Borderlands I found only 1 relic that did something similar after 400 hours of play...could never find another.

Comment: @SadlyNot Relics in borderlands 1? Do you mean the class mods? Getting more items dropped mods are rather common. IF you play siren or hunter. The others simply do not get + item mods.

Comment: @Ids they weren't *that* common...I found all of one for Hunter, rather low level...and a friend sold it because he didn't use it. Never found another Hunter mod like that, found some Siren ones though.

Comment: Yeah but only once in 400 hours? I found them a lot more. You do need to check the shops of course.

Comment: @Ids Yeah I meant class mods, but there were class mods similar to what relics do now. Maybe I didn't check shops enough, or I'm just *really* unlucky.

Comment: The vault hunters relic decreases the percentage of white/green loot by an amount to increase other rarities being dropped, so say the infinity pistol had a 1% the relic will decrease white/green% leaving effectively "more percentage" to spare for it to drop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vault Hunter Relic is the **only** relic that improves rare item chance.

In Borderlands 2 you can find **Basic** and **Legendary** relics.

**Basic Relics**

- **Vitality**: Increases health stats.
- **Stockpile**: Increases your ammo storage for different types of ammo.
- **Protection**: Improves shield capabilities and damage absorption.
- **Strength**: Improves melee abilities.
- **Resistance**: Limits damage you take from different types of weapons.
- **Tenacity**: Intensifies Second Wind abilities.
- **Proficiency**: Decreases the action skill cool down rate.
- **Elemental**: Provides an increase to elemental weapon damage.
- **Aggression**: Provides a boost to a particular weapon type.
- **Allegiance**: Reserved manufacturers products improved.

**Legendary Relics**

- **Lucrative Opportunity**
  It causes shop timers to count down faster.
- **Deputy’s Badge**
  It increases “Fight For Your Life Time” by 10% for every player who has this relic equipped. Location: Showdown
- **Sheriff’s Badge**
  It increases “Fight For Your Life Time” by 15% for every player who has this relic on them. However, it is very rare and so more difficult to find. Location: Sheriff (Lynchwood)
- **Moxxi’s Endowment**
  It increases the amount of XP earned by killing enemies but is rare. Location: The Good The Bad And The Mordicai Mission, Moxxi’s Endowment
- **Vault Hunter**
  It enhances the probability of enemy dropping rare loot. It is also rare.
- **The Afterburner**
  It intensifies vehicle boost capabilities and it is rare too. Location: Positive Self-Image

Comment: Deputy's badge also had some weird bonus for Shotguns IIRC. But yeah none of those sound worth messing with

Comment: See Feeble's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The [above answer by ChrisHatez](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86191/4797) covered the varieties of relic pretty well but it's also worth noting that the Vault Hunter's Relic is far less useful than it appears. It doesn't actually increase the drop rate of Purples, E-Tech or Orange weapons, only of greens and blues and even then, the increase is tiny. I made the same mistake as you, never unequipping it but you really are better off using something else given how little a difference it makes.

> So I just investigated the Vault Hunter Relic data.
>
> It modifies two attributes:
>
> GD_Balance.Weighting.GearDrops_RareWeightModifier: +0.05
>   GD_Balance.Weighting.GearDrops_CommonWeightModifier: -0.06
>
> [Let's set them to +100.00 and -100.00!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6jIf.jpg) 
>   [image]
>
> Net result: I have not seen a single white weapon drop, greens drop,
>   seen a few blues. Nothing else.
>
> So, what I can gauge from this, is that it shifts a 5% of your chance
>   for whites into non-whites. Doesn't touch anything else. Very low
>   impact, perhaps bordering on useless.

<sup>Source: http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3504490&pagenumber=133&perpage=40#post408051645 (page is now not viewable by unregistered users; [same post quoted in the Gearbox forums](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=2881908&postcount=24))</sup>

Comment: You need to have a somethingawful.com account (which is not free) if you want to access the page in your link. Could you quote the relevant parts of that page for those of us unable to access it?