# Increase chance of rare loot drops

Tags: borderlands-2

I have the Vault Hunter's Relic which increases the chance of rare loot drops by 5%. Unfortunately, I am very displeased with the rarity settings of the game in general. I would like to know if there is any way to mod the game to make vending machines and enemies drop rare loot more often.

For example, it would be nice if that 5% in the Relic could be upped to something like 25%. I am level 21 at the moment and almost all of the weapons and stuff I find and see in vending machines is white. It is a rare pleasure to see green stuff, and blue/purple almost never happens. I would like to somehow mod this game to make rare stuff at least somewhat less rare.

If anybody knows of a way to do this either by modding the game or the relic above, I'd really appreciate it. I don't want to cheat completely via the golden chest, btw, just increase the chance of getting rare items in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85931/1134 Only difference is this one relates to modding the game, and should probably be more generic if you want to talk about save game/item modding because once that is done, whether its relic or weapon doesn't matter much. And if you're modding, why bother with a rare loot chance increase; why not just mod in the rare loot you want?

Comment: Because I want it to be random, just better chances that's all...

Comment: At your level I would expect to start seeing green weapons from chests pretty soon. I am at level 32 and get pretty much at least all green guns from chests

Comment: Rarer stuff is more common later on; at level 41 I'm seeing mostly green items in chests, and purples aren't uncommon. Orange has been extremely rare but I'm hoping that's less the case at level 50

Comment: As for modding the game you'll probably have to wait for Willow Tree 2.0, and they probably put more work into obfusicating this stuff this time

Answer (score 4):

The Vault Hunter's Relic only drops the chances of white item drops by 5% and then splits that 5% between the green and blue drops.  so say if the odds of drops are:

No drop:40%, white:30%, green:15%, blue:10%, purple:5%, orange:Only on named & bosses (and often about 1% or less there) OR 3 borderlands symbols on a slot machine (about a 1 in 5,000 chance)

The Vault Hunters Relic would only make that:

No drop:40%, white:25%, green:18%, blue:12%, purple:5%, orange:Only on named & bosses (and often about 1% or less there) OR 3 borderlands symbols on a slot machine (about a 1 in 5,000 chance)

assuming those numbers were accurate (the orange is pretty close but the others I am mearly speculating) then even if it were modded to be a 30% better chance (thus eliminating white drops all together) it would still only be about: None:40%, White:0%, Green:38%, Blue:17%, Purple:5%, Orange:special.

No modding of %'s will make the Vault Hunters Relic really worth wearing once others become an option. Better to wear a relic that works to improve your strengths (such as an elemental boost on a siren or a brand-specific relic that helps boost your best weapon) or compensate for a weakness (+shield capacity or max health if you find yourself dying too easily).

Answer (score 0):

A few of my friends had an idea to get four of us in a co-op game, that itself will give you a boost in the rare item drops, 
but we had a thought that what if we all equiped the vault hunters relic, will it put the rare drop up to 20%?? 
why dont you see if you can get 3 other friends together with that relic, and see what happens.

hope that helps somewhat