# How can I get up to the Sheriff of Lynchwood?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've just killed the Sheriff of Lynchwood, but she never came down from the top of the building.  [An answer to another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86191/4586) leads me to believe that she might have dropped something interesting, but I just haven't been able to figure out how to get up there.

Is it possible, or was I supposed to have gotten her to drop down before shooting her?

Comment: A Singularity Grenade may be able to pull her down

Comment: I also was not able to get up there to grab her loot (a little of it fell down to reachable spots)

Comment: If I remember correctly, sheriff drops a pistol & the deputy accompanying her drops deputy badge relic which increase shotgun damage and reload speed. don't worry if you missed her first time, She re-spawns and could be killed multiple times.

Comment: When I was fighting her, she actually jumped down on her own. Don't know if that is supposed to happen, but she did it. Which made it much easier to grab her loot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a little help from what's basically the [same question at gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/638784-borderlands-2/64158816), I was able to figure it out.

As their instructions are a little confusing ('across the street' and any of the cardinal directions mentioned are flat out wrong), the working instructions are:

- From standing in front of the building, facing where the Sheriff had been.
- Turn to your left, and go to the neighboring building.
- Just past the building will be some crates; jump up those.
- On top of this building is a sign with two diagonal braces; walk up one of the braces.
- From the top of the sign, jump over to the next level of the building.
- Walk out on the rod heading towards the Sheriff's building
- Jump off the rod *before* it becomes a cable.

It's actually relatively easy, once you figure out that you can walk up the sign supports.  (I had originally tried jumping onto the sign directly)

Answer (score 2):

On your way there, you should see a stack of crates on one of the sides of the buildings. Get on top of that, look around and you should see 2 metal poles propping up a sign. Walk till you’re at the top of that, turn around and jump on top of the building closest to where the sheriff spawns. You should be able to find another metal pole going towards the sheriff and a quick run+jump and you'll be there.

Answer (score 2):

When I killed her she jumped over to a building to the right, Her left. I Found out how to get up to the first building thanks to *Joe*. The second build I got up on by NOT jumping over to it Directly. but going around the Invisible wall. 
At first i tried to jump over to it. But was stopped by the invisible wall there. I Got back up to the first Building she was on. then walked over to the end of it and jumped over to the roof of the second building. then jumped down. Boo for invisible walls in wrong places
This is from *Joe*

With a little help from what's basically the same question at GameFAQs, I was able to figure it out.

As their instructions are a little confusing ('across the street' and any of the cardinal directions mentioned are flat out wrong), the working instructions are:

From standing in front of the building, facing where the Sheriff had been.
Turn to your left, and go to the neighboring building.
Just past the building will be some crates; jump up those.
On top of this building is a sign with two diagonal braces; walk up one of the braces.
From the top of the sign, jump over to the next level of the building.
Walk out on the rod heading towards the Sheriff's building
Jump off the rod before it becomes a cable.
It's actually relatively easy, once you figure out that you can walk up the sign supports. (I had originally tried jumping onto the sign directly)